# How to get graph names after converting a graph to adj matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, graph, networkx

Currently, I've constructed a bipartite graph for funds and stocks data.

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'fund_code', 'stock_data', edge_attr='weight')
print(G.edges())

>>>
[('159957.SZ', '300070.SZ'), ('159957.SZ', '300027.SZ'), ('159957.SZ', '300003.SZ'), ('159958.SZ', '300017.SZ'), ('159958.SZ', '300136.SZ') ... ]
```

Then I converted the graph to adj matrix to do some calculation.

```
A = nx.adj_matrix(G)
print("getcol ", A.getrow(0))

>>>
getcol   
  (0, 1)    0.06296851574212893
  (0, 2)    0.06296851574212893
  (0, 3)    0.05247376311844078
  (0, 4)    0.20689655172413793
  ... ...
```

My question is how to map the node `0, 1, 2 ...` in the `matrix A` to `159957.SZ', '300070.SZ' ...` in `graph G`? 
For example, if I has a list of `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]`, is there a convenient way to covert the array to `` [`159957.SZ`, `159959.SZ', `159995.SZ' ...] ``? Thanks

Comment: def adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=None, weight='weight'):
    """Returns adjacency matrix of G.

    Parameters
    ----------
    G : graph
       A NetworkX graph

    nodelist : list, optional
       The rows and columns are ordered according to the nodes in nodelist.
       If nodelist is None, then the ordering is produced by G.nodes().

Comment: IMO G.nodes() could be enough